# Alerting HTML elements with .ajax using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, alert

Is there a way of alerting all of the HTML from this .ajax get?

```
function testq() {    
    var acronyms = ["fubar", "snafu", "gnu"];

    $.each(acronyms, function(index, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=" + element,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                var $container = $("#leftnav", html); // look for a specific element in the returned HTML
                jAlert($container);
            }
        });
    });
}​
```

This is just for debugging. I will later be modifying the information gotten from the .ajax page get.

Comment: I can't understand what is the question? what do you want to modify-alter?

Comment: if you are doing this for debugging, I suggest using a proper console, like firebug, or chrome built-in console, and inspect the returned value from ajax call there, rather than trying to alert

Comment: Hi. Firstly I'd like to alert all of the HTML that my request gets. That way I get an idea of what I am working with. Thanks.

Comment: By the way: why are you calling server several times? This is an overheat. Don't you have control over sever side? You should pass all the acronyms in one ajax request.

Comment: @derek8. Did my answer is what you're looking for? I'm feel like I still don't get it.

Comment: @freakish I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @derek8 Hold the acronyms as a hash, for example: `acronyms = { q1: "fubar", q2:"snafu", a3:"gnu" };` and then `$.ajax({ data: acronyms, ... });`. JQuery will append the data to your query string for GET request. Then you have to handle it on the server side. There are several other ways (without explicite defining keys). Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly I'd like to alert all of the HTML that my request gets.

You alert only one specific element:

```
var $container = $("#leftnav", html); // look for a specific element in the returned HTML
jAlert($container);
```

Change to

```
jAlert(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `$container` use `html`:

```
jAlert(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jAlert($container.html())` to get the html content of your `jQuery` object or simply `jAlert(html)` to get everything, but if you are doing this for debugging, I suggest using a proper console, like firebug, or chrome built-in console, and inspect the returned value from ajax call there, rather than trying to alert

Answer (score 0):

use `jAlert(html);`..........................................................